# renv::status() returns Error in seq_len(length(splat) - 1) :

Tags: r, renv

I ran

```
renv::status()
```

and got back:

```
Error in seq_len(length(splat) - 1) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

I tried `traceback()` and got back:

```
f(n[[i]], x[[i]], ...)
7: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
6: lapply(idx, callback)
5: enumerate(fields, function(section, entries) {
       splat <- strsplit(section, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
       for (i in seq_len(length(splat) - 1)) {
           k <- splat[1:i]
           if (is.null(data[[k]])) 
               data[[k]] <<- list()
       }
       data[[splat]] <<- entries
   })
4: renv_lockfile_read(lockpath)
3: renv_status_check_missing_lockfile(project, lockpath)
2: renv_status_impl(project, libpaths, lockpath, cache)
1: renv::status()
```

Where do I begin troubleshooting?

P.S. I am on Windows 10 and R 4.0.4

**Update**
Here is renv.lock file

[renv.lock](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_Muu0RZ9WonYcDFv00u6M0DPWP5lh6-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The stack trace suggests your lockfile has an unexpected structure. Are you able to share the contents of your lockfile?

Comment: @KevinUshey I updated post with a link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lockfile has merge conflict markers embedded:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
      "Hash": "97def703420c8ab10d8f0e6c72101e02"
=======
      "Hash": "97def703420c8ab10d8f0e6c72101e02",
      "Requirements": [
        "magrittr",
        "rlang"
      ]
>>>>>>> 3f3484f01258197d106dc7e7bcdec33784407f38
    },
```

You'll need to manually edit and remove those from your lockfile.

Comment: Agreed, I also had this when I had a trailing comma after manually editing the version (naughty I know)